# Weird selection problem, selected the unselecting one

Tags: selection-tools

I have no idea why I select goes wrong like this. Especially when I meet the situation is that I did not even touch any of its, it still selected by me. 
Would anyone meet the same problem as like I do? and how to solve this, please? 
I reinstalled and re-download the newer one, still the same. (using 2.79 and 2.79a)

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance have vertex and edge select mode enabled at the same time?

Comment: could be a problem with opengl. I can't get Blender to do the same on my machines so far

Comment: It's vertex selection mode only.  T.T

Comment: Thank you, @RayMairlot. It works. after I make sure the "See if disabling anti-aliasing in the graphics card control panel helps.
". then everything ok now. Thanks a lot.